# Detecting presence of "Drawn text" under the mouse?

Tags: c#, wpf

and thanks for taking a peek at my conundrum. 
I am trying to write a series of strings to an image as overlays, then later be able to come back and move, or delete one of them selectively using WPF framework...
I've been looking into the FindVisualChildren function, but for the moment cant make heads or tails of how to detect the proximity to the mouse (for selectivity), or actually detect one of my created strings (Perhaps I should be making them dynamic 'Label' elements...????)
Insomnia sucks, and my brains are turning to mush.
TIA for any advice!

Okay, sorry for the lack of sample code, been a long night... well two nights actually (See earlier comment about insomnia)

```
public void WriteTextToImage(Point position) 
{
  ImageSource bitmapSource = imgFrame.Source;
  var vis = new DrawingVisual();

  using (DrawingContext drawingContext = vis.RenderOpen())
  {
    // Set the pen color... Why is this called a brush if it's for
    // writing? perhaps I should overload it and call it crayon?
    SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)cpColor.SelectedColor);
    drawingContext.DrawImage(bitmapSource, new Rect(0, 0, imgFrame.Source.Width, imgFrame.Source.Height)); 

    //Write some pretty words, (actually print some general stuff)
    drawingContext.DrawText(new FormattedText(tbCurrentLabel.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Arial"), slFontSize.Value, brush),position); 
  }

  //Slap this puppy to the screen
  var image = new DrawingImage(vis.Drawing);

  //Iterate the label text to the next digit or value
  IterateLabel();
}
```

Basically what will happen is the user will click the screen in several places to make marks on the image for printing, but I want to include support to move those marks, and delete them as needed.
I hope this explains what I am trying to accomplish a little better.

Thanks again!

Comment: This is hard to answer unless you tell us exactly how you've added the text overlays on top of an image. If they are e.g. TextBlocks in a Canvas, you may simply add mouse event handlers to them.

Comment: I'd love to peek at your conundrum, you naughty thing, but I can't see it from here, because you didn't show any code.

Comment: Use a Canvas control and then add the text on the Canvas via TextBlock objects. You can then use Mouse.DirectlyOver() to get a reference to the element that is under the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! thanks NineBerry, I figured it was going to be something like that. I was originally thinking a label, but the textblock worked perfectly.

Here's the updated code showing how I am getting it done now.

`public void WriteTextToImage(Point position)`
`{`
 `SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)cpColor.SelectedColor);`
`//Get something to write on (not an old receipt...)`
`TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();`
`//Say something useful... well something atleast...`
`textBlock.Text = tbCurrentLabel.Text;`
`textBlock.FontSize = slFontSize.Value;`
`textBlock.Foreground = brush;`
`Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, position.X);`
`Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, position.Y);`
`canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);`

`//Need to update the canvas, was not seeing children before doing this.`
`canvas.UpdateLayout();`

            //Iterate the label text
            IterateLabel();
        }`